# Vertically align center in a bootstrap modal when the image is small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootstrap modal to show images of different sizes. And I would like that the modal body has minimal width and height (600*400 actually). So when an image is bigger it expands and works well, but when the image has a height inferior to 400px, the image is aligned (vertically) at the top. So I would like to align it vertically in the middle of the modal body.

I have tried:

```
.vcenter {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     float: none;
}
```

and

```
.image-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

on the object tag but doesn't work well.

Here is my css (the object represent the image):

```
 object  {
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 70vh;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
  }

  .modal-header {
    text-align: left;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px){
    .modal-dialog {
      max-width: 95%;
    }
    .modal-body{
      min-width: 600px;
      min-height: 400px;
    }
  }

  .modal-dialog {
      width: auto;      
      text-align: center;
    }

  .modal-content{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

and my html for one modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <object data="https://og.github.com/mark/github-mark@1200x630.png" type="image/png">
        </object>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is also a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIKJ9beA77x4R0wyD7KS?p=preview) showing the comparison between the behavior with the small image and a bigger one.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

```
object  {
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 70vh;
 }
```

Have a nice day !

Comment: It seems to work but prevent the modal to be bigger than 600px. That's not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Valentin Darricau** Hi there.
Try this **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tb0gavLy/)**, to see if this works for how you want.
To have the small image align in the center vertically.

This is the class I added.

```
.centerthis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
```

And used it here...

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <object class="centerthis" data="https://wasin.io/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/showimage.png" type="image/png">
    </object>
</div>
```

**Added**

Here is a image of your original code with the modal. 
[image]

Here is a image of the modal body using the class of **centerthis**

[image]

Comment: This class is already in the question. I have tried this, but it doesn't work in the big image. In fact I don't know in advance what is the size of the image that's the tricky part.

Comment: Hi there, I have added to my post above. This should work for either modal body and should center an image whatever the size. When I first read your post it sounded like you were just having a issue for the small option. Have another look at the fiddle and try using different size images to see if it works for you.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I need. But anyway I choose to make it another way. But thanks for trying.