# Center fit images of any size to parent div

Tags: html, css

I've got an image slider, the selected image is set as the main image above. All the images are not same size. How do I make sure that each image is centered in the parent div and the entire parent div?

I'm now doing it with:

```
width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit:fill;
```

but then my image loses the bottom of its content. I would like to center the image vertically.

My parent div has following class style:

```
.wrapper_image{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

code:

```
<div class="o-grid__col u-12/12" style="width: 400px;
          height: 400px;
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0;">
          <div class="mySlides wrapper_image_horses">
          <img src='url' style="width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit:fill;">
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you use inline css? It only gives problems...

Comment: just for testing

Comment: typ in internet slideshow you will see tons of examples

Comment: yes, but I need this :p

Comment: can you make a fiddle? or codepen?

Comment: This thread helped me out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594968/vertically-align-center-in-a-bootstrap-modal-when-the-image-is-small

Comment: so you don't need help anymore?

Comment: The only problem is that the image is not filling the parent div anymore.. I already added 'object-fit: fill;' to the css of the image

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use `display: flex;` to achieve this. With flex it is much easier for you to align you images to center vertically and horizontally. Below is a test code I have done. Hope it helps with your problem

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <div class="img-slide">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.h-100 {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/y5fzvox8/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modern solution, hope it will help you

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/dikiladano/1/edit?html,output)

```
<div class="o-grid__col u-12/12" style="width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid #000;">
      <div class="mySlides wrapper_image_horses" style="position: absolute;
                  top: 50%; left: 50%;
                  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/159/200/200' style="width: auto;height: auto;">
      </div>
```

Comment: using this, the image is shown in his original shape

Comment: I found out the following. The image is in a pop up window. The vertical alignment is on the full page but not on the pop up

Comment: @belgiums have you succeed in solving this problem?